# How to remove whitespaces from a pyspark dataframe column and save it to a CSV file

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark

Does anyone know how to remove white spaces from a dataframe before saving it to csv file.

For me file is saving with NUL whitespace for every record.

Filename.csv

```
NUL 1, AAA, 123, NUL
NUL 2, BBB, 456, NUL
....
...
NUL n, NNN, 789 NUL
```

Expected output:

```
 1, AAA, 123,
 2, BBB, 456,
....
...
 n, NNN, 789
```

I have tried few functions like trim, strip, option(leadingwhitespace and trailing white space but not working.

My code

```
df.write.mode('overwrite').format('csv').option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace", True).option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", True).save(hdfs/path)
```

My file is saving from a dataframe as above sample data with extra NUL white spaces in the beginning and end of each record.
Please help if anyone came across this issue.

I have tried few functions like trim, strip, option(leadingwhitespace and trailing white space but not working as expected.

Comment: The letters NUL are literal strings. You'll need to use string replacement

Comment: Actually I'm getting a NUL whitespace while saving dataframe into a CSV file as I have highlighted above. I have tried regexp_replace with some space to replace it but no luck

Comment: Show `df.show()`, without writing. writing shouldn't add characters that aren't really there. And we can't reproduce the issue by copying the text you've provided since it's not actually "whitespace". Can you [edit] your question to include that regex attempt as well?